# How to consumer messages with 2 consumers with same group-id?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I want to be able to consume data once from 2 different consumers (each consumer will get different messages) when using same `topic` and same `group-id`.

The producer:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                             value_serializer=lambda x:
                             dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
    for e in range(50):
        data = {'number' : e}
        print('Producer {}'.format(data))
        producer.send('test', value=data)
        sleep(2)
```

The first consumer code:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'test',
        bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
        auto_offset_reset='earliest',
        enable_auto_commit=True,
        #auto_commit_interval_ms=100,
        group_id='my-group',
        value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
    print('[1] Consume {}'.format(message))
    sleep(3)
```

The second consumer code:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'test',
        bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
        auto_offset_reset='earliest',
        enable_auto_commit=True,
        #auto_commit_interval_ms=100,
        group_id='my-group',
        value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

 for message in consumer:
        message = message.value
        print('[2] Consume {}'.format(message))
        sleep(5)
```

I'm expecting to see that some of the messages are consumed by `consumer-1` and the other messages by `consumer-2` (according to the sleep command in `consumer` code)

But it seems that just one consumer is working and gets all the messages. (The first consumer is stuck, and the second consumer gets the messages).

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of the problem, I assume your topic only has one partition.

Your topic needs more than one partition if you want to run more than one consumer in a group